# Permutations in alphabetical order

Tags: permutation, python-itertools

I want to get a list of every permutation from AAAA to ZZZZ, and I want the list to be made in alphabetical order. How do I do this?

Comment: This has clearly nothing to do with permutation please consult http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way to use the proper terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:

```
alphabet = [chr(item) for item in xrange(ord('A'), ord('Z')+1)]
```

Creates the alphabet from capital A to capital Z.

```
perms    = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat = 4)
```

Creates a generator that will produce all of the 4-character permutations from `'AAAA'` to `'ZZZZ'`

```
results  = sorted((''.join(item) for item in perms))
```

Sorts the results (note that `product` returns a tuple of 4 chars, so we need to combine them with `join`) alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

In python standard library have functions for iterators for efficient looping which name is itertools. The itertools have permutation generators.

The permutation function needs two arguments, one is iterable, another one is length like if the iterable is “ABC” and length is 2 then (A,B) (A,C) (B,A) (B,C) (C,A) (C,B) are results for this functions.
Generate permutation

Comment: 1) The OP is aware of itertools, as the tag demonstrates. They don't know how to use it, so a general description is not very helpful. 2) As pointed out by the answer from 2014 (!), the question has nothing to do with permutations. They are looking for the Cartesian product. An answer should reflect this.